# Using Gson fromJson method not working

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a json string that is represented as below:

```
 "{"RequestId":255,
  "RequestTime":"2016-04-08T17:00:40.327",
  "Otp":"123456",
  "AppName":"This is my app name",
  "IsAwaitingResponse":false}"
```

I also have a class object below that I wish to create using the Gson library fromJson() method...

```
public class AccessRequest{
    public int Id;
    public String RequestTime;
    public String Otp;
    public String AppName;
    public Boolean IsAwaitingResponse;
}
```

Now when I call the gson.fromJson method it does not error but my object is not getting set. This is the code I'm using...

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
AccessRequest ar;
ar = gson.fromJson(jsonString, AccessRequest.class);
```

It is instead setting my 'ar' variable to some strange gson object that clearly is wrong but no error is thrown.

> {serializeNulls:falsefactories:[Factory[typeHierarchy=com.google.gson.JsonElement,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$25@e8dad0a],

From what I can see, there is no error in my Json string ( although I am new to json ) , so I'm not really sure why this method wouldn't be working...

Comment: Where do you get that output? What generates it?

Comment: Can you post a MCVE?

Comment: What's the exception that contains that error message? Post the stacktrace please.

Comment: I bet you printed the `gson`, instead of `ar`. Voting to close as typo, unreproducible.

Comment: RequestId and Id should be the same, or you use the @SerializedName annotation..

Answer (score 1):

You probably printed the `gson` object instead of the `ar` object, as @Pillar noted in the comments.

I've tried your example and it works as expected. Also, the `Id` field is not being set because the name of the property does not match. You should use `@SerializedName` or change any of the names. This has also been noted in the comments.

This is the working example:

```
package net.sargue.gson;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.intellij.lang.annotations.Language;

public class SO36553536 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    @Language("JSON")
    String json = "{\n" +
            "  \"RequestId\": 255,\n" +
            "  \"RequestTime\": \"2016-04-08T17:00:40.327\",\n" +
            "  \"Otp\": \"123456\",\n" +
            "  \"AppName\": \"This is my app name\",\n" +
            "  \"IsAwaitingResponse\": false\n" +
            "}";

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    AccessRequest ar;
    ar = gson.fromJson(json, AccessRequest.class);
    System.out.println("ar.getClass() = " + ar.getClass());
    System.out.println("ar = " + ar);
  }

  public class AccessRequest {
    public int Id;
    public String RequestTime;
    public String Otp;
    public String AppName;
    public Boolean IsAwaitingResponse;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "AccessRequest{" + "Id=" + Id +
              ", RequestTime='" + RequestTime + '\'' +
              ", Otp='" + Otp + '\'' +
              ", AppName='" + AppName + '\'' +
              ", IsAwaitingResponse=" + IsAwaitingResponse +
              '}';
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the execution output:

```
ar.getClass() = class net.sargue.gson.SO36553536$AccessRequest
ar = AccessRequest{Id=0
, RequestTime='2016-04-08T17:00:40.327'
, Otp='123456'
, AppName='This is my app name'
, IsAwaitingResponse=false}
```

Comment: The appropriate action here is to vote/flag to close as unreproducible.

Answer (score 0):

As just need to change RequestId from Id class AccessRequest.
you will get proper output.